# What is the estimation techniques used in lm() in R?

Tags: r, regression

I'm wondering what is the estimation techniques used in lm(). If it's OLS, how could we perform a log likelihood test by logLik()? What's the difference between lm() and ols(), mle() and other functions?

Comment: `lm` uses OLS. The basic algorithm (the same one used in most packages) is described [here](stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90402/algorithm-for-minimization-of-sum-of-squares-in-regression-packages). There's no `ols` or `mle` function that I could find in the distribution of R; there may be more than one such function elsewhere -- what packages are you talking about?

Comment: `ols` is part of the `rms` package. It apparently provides better support for categorical variables, but mostly breaks compatibility with any functions expecting `lm` output. Not surprising in this duct-tape universe of R.